# Apache showing coldfusion code instead of executing the web page

Tags: apache, coldfusion

I am trying to setup multiple coldfusion sites on my mac locally. But I am seeing the code instead of web page. I have spent hours tried looking up all the settings for the vhosts.conf etc. I am not sure what I am missing Any ideas will be greatly appreciated. [I have tried to do what has been discussed in this tutorial](https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/how-to-set-up-virtual-hosts-in-apache-on-macos-osx-sierra/)

Comment: If you don't need Apache (eg for mod_rewrite or something) then I would recommend you use commandbox instead. It is as simple as downloading it, then cd to your directory and run: `box server start cfengine=adobe@2016`

Comment: Can i set up multiple sites using commandbox?

Comment: I was able to install coldfusion on commandbox, when i go to my localhost i am still seeing only the code! Am I missing some setting ?

Comment: I mean, with most servers you need to associate .cfm and .cfc files with the ColdFusion. I'm not sure if that happens automatically during install, but check your mime types.

Comment: Your Apache does not know about your ColdFusion. Run the ColdFusion connector again.

Comment: OK, i was able to get the site running in commandbox. But I have to use http://127.0.0.1:63653/ localhost with the port number. How do I rename the url to something like site1.new in commandbox?

Comment: CommandBox will spin up each server on a new port - you can tell it to run on port 80, but there can only be one commandbox server (web root) that could run on port 80. Also to use port 80 on unix you need to be root. You can tell it what port to use by doing `box server start port=8000` .

Comment: If you really want all running on port 80, you can setup a proxy server on Apache using ProxyPass and then proxy to each of your internal servers. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass you might ask why use CommandBox at all if you are still involving apache, and that is a valid question, but commandbox lets you switch CF versions very easily so it has a lot of advantages as well.

Comment: I am not sure I understand fully, I was able to give the site a name site1.new. But it only works when there is the port like site1.new:63653. Is there any way I cannot use the port number. I need to configure 4 such sites. So clearly i dont want to run on port 80. But I need a way to escape the port number from the site as few pages break because of the port number.

Comment: @ Pete Freitag any ideas?